# Are all CMBR entangled with each other even today?

Tags: quantum-entanglement, cosmic-microwave-background

Just curious: since at the very beginning they are all so close together so I suspect all of them are entangled together, it is possible?

Comment: cmbr? Please spell out acronyms. Also, who or what is "they"?

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/186743/) though there are no answers.

Comment: The current question is not the same as the one provided above. That one asked about the feasibility of an experimental measurement. This question here (although not well phrased) asks about the possible mechanism that could cause such entanglement.

Comment: @josephh In response, I have added an answer at the question you referenced.